# weird border/whitespace around image on printing html to pdf

Tags: html, css, pdf, printing

When printing (output PDF) the following html there is sometimes an unwanted border/whitespace around the images. Sometimes it appears on the right side other times on the left side. It appears to be just one pixel wide.

I have already tried `display: block;` to no avail.

How can I get rid of the whitespace around the image?

body:

```
<body>
  <div class="doc">
    <div class="container-row">
      <div class="container leftSide">
        <div class="item">Item A</div>
        <img class="image" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x450">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container-row">
      <div class="container rightSide">
        <div class="item">Item A</div>
        <img class="image" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x450">
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- plus more "container-row"s -->
  </div>
</body>
```

relevant part of css:

```
@media print {
  .container-row {
    page-break-inside: avoid;
  }
}

body {
  background-color: transparent;
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
}

.doc {
  font-size: 0;
}

.container-row {
  display: inline-block; 
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px transparent solid; 
  font-size: 10px;
}

.container {
  max-width: 75%;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  margin: 10px 10px 0px 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.image {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 5px 0px -5px;
}

.leftSide {
  float: left;
  border-top-left-radius: 13px;
  border-top-right-radius: 13px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 13px;
}

.rightSide {
  float: right;
  border-top-left-radius: 13px;
  border-top-right-radius: 13px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 13px;
}

.item {
  margin: 7px 10px 1px 10px;
}

.container p {
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 7px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem by adjusting the css for the `image` class to:

```
.image {
  width: 102%;
  margin: 5px -1% -5px;
}
```